# Firefox 5 opens too many instances with one click

Tags: browser, firefox

I'm using latest Firefox 5.

Since last week, when I run Firefox by clicking the shortcut, it runs 6 instances instead of one instance.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Do you happen to have one of those "minimize to tray" add-ons enabled?

Comment: yes but not with firefox, I got it on thunderbird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled FF and deleted all profile folders...Then I reinstalled it...It works normal now but I could not find the root cause...

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just restoring the last state?

Try closing all of them one by one with Ctrl-W, and then lastly close the one you want to keep with Ctrl-W or Ctrl-Q.

Comment: no, first one restores the last state, the others are blank...

Comment: ok, thanks... I've never seen this behaviour either, only other thing that I can think of is that a script in one of the tabs in the first instance is spawning the extra windows, but I would expect that you've checked these too. Firebug plugin may shed some light, or if you're using Windows there might be something unexpected in the registry. Perhaps the blunt approach of a reinstall will solve it, but not explain why.